# How do I accomodate for large values of K in this expanding substring?

Tags: string, algorithm

So I have been given 2 strings, A and B, with lengths <= 6.

Now, the nth string (n>2) is calculated as ABB (concatenating n-1 + 2*n-2).
I want to find the kth letter in the entire concatenation.

I was able to do it for small values of k, but k could be upto 10^18 and that is where my solution fails.

Can anyone help me with a possible efficient solution?

Eg:
A="ab", B="c", n=4.
Now for k=7, the answer is "b".

Reasoning:
cabccabcc and the seventh character will be b.

Comment: What is the n-th String? Could you be more precise about the meaning of N? Is it the same as lower case n from the second paragraph?

Comment: sorry, it is the same. Edited.

Comment: Do you mean you have a sequence of strings beginning `['B', 'A', ...]` and the rule is that `strings[n] == strings[n-1] + strings[n-2] + strings[n-2]`? You've given us the maximum size of `k`, but what is the maximum that `n` could be?

Answer (score 1):

I have working code, but I suspect it is homework and think having you figure it out will help you.  So I'll describe the idea and let you try to code it.

You should solve this with recursion.

Your two base cases are that you are in the first `A` or the first `B`.  You can just compare lengths.  If `k <= len(A)` you are in `A`.  If `k <= len(A) + len(B)` then you are in `B`.  Either way you look up the character.  (Don't be surprised if getting the base cases right involves a few one-off errors, that is normal.)

Your recursive case works like this.  First you build a list of the lengths of the strings until you find one where `k` fits inside.  In your case that list is `[2, 1, 4, 9]`.  (The rule being that `lengths[i] = lengths[i-2] + 2*lengths[i-1]`.

Now you know that you are in an `ABB` pattern.  And you know the lengths of `A` and `B`.  Subtract off the length of the `A`.  Subtract off the length of the first `B` if you can.  Then recurse.

In your example you are in an `ABB` pattern where `A` has length 1 and `B` has length 4.  So you start with `k=7`, subtract off 1, subtract off 4 (because 4 < 6) and now you are facing the same problem only with `k=2`.

Recurse and you find that you want the second letter of `A`, which is `b`.

For `10**18` you wind up needing only 29 recursive calls.  It basically runs instantly.

Comment: As a side-note, since the recurrence relation is linear, the solution can be written in a closed form and hence computed even more efficiently. But if only 29 steps are needed for the dynamic programming algorithm then it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @kaya3 Actually you keep building the lengths array.  So it was more steps than recursive calls.  But it still runs fast enough that it is hard to imagine that a smarter implementation is worthwhile.